# My R.java file can't regenerate (Clean method)

Tags: java, android, xml

Many people have the same problem, the R file. In my case, i have some differents packages from different projects, and then different R files. When i import all of theses packages into one, and all of R file and layouts, they(the R files) disappeared.

My question is : How i can fix this ? I had some manipulations, like the Clean method, but nothing change, and the R file never comeback :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Delete the "gen" folder.
- Clean project through Project -> Clean...

if this doesn't help, you may have a bad file name or bad encoded string in your project.
Open the error file in the "gen" folder, scroll to the error.. if it's a string, just change it. If it's a bad file name, rename it.

Don't use capitalized letters in file names other than classes, no spaces...

If you have a string in a UTF-8 required language, make sure your editor is set to UTF-8 in Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Text file encoding.

Comment: I have this error when i do that : R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version! The problem is i don't have any solution to revert

Comment: @toshiro92 why you want to revert? Eclipse automatically generates the gen folder.. but it generates a bad gen folder.. because of something wrong. Open the R.java file and scroll to the error... as I wrote, probably a bad filename, missing file, bad encoding for a string.

Comment: The R file doesn't exist, it erased when i clean up the project... I tried to export to a new project but now, i have :

"Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\...\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist"
I just copied the main.xml, and used the default Activity to launch it. I don't see what's the problem

Comment: @toshiro92 Create a new android project. a clean one. go to its location on the hard drive. copy the files from the old project to it in the right locations -> classes to the packages, replace the manifest, put the layouts, drawables, etc... go back to eclipse, refresh and that's it. It should work. if not, you're doing something wrong or have something wrong in your old project.

Comment: Thanks @liorry, i forgot copy the drawable folder into the project. The layout needed that. Now Clean method work :) Thanks for your method too, it can help me one day :)

Answer (score 0):

Never import any R.java. If you have any auto imported package saying import R.java, delete that as well. Clean should solve the issue. If not, then check if you have made any recent change in your xml file. At times, reverting back to your previous change solves this issue. If not, create a new project all over again. Track back your issue from where its generated

Comment: I tried to do re-create a project, but when i copy a layout in there, all ids presents in this file aren't added in R.java, and clean method delete the R file.

Answer (score 0):

R.java is generated automatically when your program builds. If it fails to build, it can't generate the R file.

This basically means you have an error somewhere in your code that's preventing it from building.

To find the error in Eclipse, use your Problems window. If it's not open, go to Window > Show View > Problems or press the hotkey: ALT+SHIFT+Q, X

The Problems window in Eclipse will show you exactly what is preventing the application from building correctly.